# The minimum possible energy for five noniteracting spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics

**Question**
What is the minimum possible energy for five **(noniteracting)** spin $\frac{1}{2}$
particles of mass $m$ in a one-dimensional box of length $L$?

**Answer:**
$$
2 \times \frac{1^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL}+2 \times \frac{2^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL}+1 \times \frac{3^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL}
$$

This answer confuses me: I would imagine that orbital and magnetic quantum numbers come into play and therefore more than two particles would fit in the $n=2$ state. The only thing I can think of is that the "noninteracting" part in the question formulation is responsible. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Maybe the key is that the box is one-dimensional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a particle-in-a-box. You only have $\ell, m$ quantum numbers in a more complicated system like an atom--in particular, there needs to be a rotational symmetry and this just isn't that kind of system.